# How to rename fields in query object within projection of mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have my event schema like below.

```
var Event = new Schema({
    eventName: {type: String, required: true},
    eventPlace: {
        name: {type: String, default:'Virtual'},
        location: {
            type: {type: String, default: 'Point'}, 
            coordinates: {type: Array, default: [0, 0]}
        },
    },
});
```

and I am trying to get the data from the schema using the following function.

```
    var criteria = { };
    var projection = {
        _id: 0,
        eventName: 1,
        "eventPlace.name": 1, //this statement working fine
        "$eventPlace.location.coordinates[0]": 1, //this statement not working
        "$eventPlace.location.coordinates[1]": 1 //this statement not working
    };
    var option = { }
    var query = Models.Event.find(criteria, projection, option) //here i am querying the database based on the projection and criteria
    query.exec(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log("data", data)
            callback(null, data);
        }
    })
```

I want to get the data in this format.

```
[{
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    placeName: dubai,
    description: nothing
},
{
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    placeName: dubai,
    description: nothing
}]
```

so for this, i want to rename the field which I am getting in the query. how should I rename my query fields and make coordinates statement work? I tried to get some understanding from the internet but unable to mold it according to my requirement. and for loop is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to project different indexes all at same time in find projection. Using aggregation.

```
 var projection = {
    "_id": 0,
    "eventName": 1,
   "eventPlace":"$eventPlace.name",
    "latitude":{$arrayElemAt:["$eventPlace.location.coordinates", 0]},
    "longitude":{$arrayElemAt:["$eventPlace.location.coordinates", 1]}
};

var query = Models.Event.aggregate([{$match:criteria},{$project:projection}])
```